# Rotate a point at a given angle

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a code that should turn a point around another point counterclockwise. But it does not work correctly.

```
public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
    double ox = this.x.get() + (this.width.get()/2);
    double oy = this.y.get() + (this.height.get()/2);
    double theta = rotate.get() - (rotate.get() * 2);
    double px1 = Math.cos(theta) * (x-ox) - Math.sin(theta) * (y-oy) + ox;
    double py1 = Math.sin(theta) * (x-ox) + Math.cos(theta) * (y-oy) + oy;
    return shape.contains(px1, py1);
}
```

x, y - are the coordinates of the point to be rotated.

ox,oy - is the coordinates of the point around which you want to rotate.

rotate.get() - angle to rotate

**Update:** Changes in the code that solved the problem, who can come in handy:

```
    double px1 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)) * (x-ox) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)) * (y-oy) + ox;
    double py1 = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)) * (x-ox) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)) * (y-oy) + oy;
```

Comment: Wjy are you doing this: `rotate.get() - (rotate.get() * 2)` - ?

Comment: In `rotate.get()` I have a positive value, which is used earlier to rotate clockwise. I also need to make a turn back, so I think it’s worth taking a `rotate.get()` with a negative value.

Comment: So .... basically ... that is an odd way of writing `-rotate.get()` - ?

Comment: Can you please provide specific values for the inputs (x, y, ox, oy and theta) so that we can validate your code?

Comment: Thanks for the help, the answer below completely solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check, if your `rotate.get()` will give you a degrees value (e.g. 45°) or a radians value (e.g. 0.5*pi). `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` will only accept radians.

To convert them you could use something like `angle = Math.toRadians(45)`

Answer (score 1):

Although this is answered, another simple way to get this done is using the built-in method of Rotate class. This way you dont need to worry about the Math stuff ;)

```
Rotate r = new Rotate();
r.setPivotX(ox);
r.setPivotY(oy);
r.setAngle(angleInDegrees);
Point2D point = r.transform(new Point2D(x, y));
```